# extend/customize Makefile syntax table

Tags: syntax-table, makefile-mode

I work with a Makefile-like infrastructure that allows having lists as variables and appending values to them. For this, the `+=` operator is used.

However, I'm having incorrect highlighting using this operator.

[image: += highlighting]

The `+` is being highlighted as part of the word. I tried doing `(modify-syntax-entry ?+ "." my-syntax-table-based-on-makefile-mode-syntax-table)` without getting the desired result (having the `+` in `+=` highlighted the same as `=`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highlighting of assignments is not syntax controlled in `makefile-mode`.
It is done via regular expressions in`makefile-font-lock-keywords`.

The list `makefile-font-lock-keywords` is constructed by the function `makefile-make-font-lock-keywords` which uses the variable **`makefile-macroassign-regex`** for macro assignments.

If you change `makefile-macroassign-regex` you must also re-run `makefile-make-font-lock-keywords` to reconstruct the font-lock keyword lists you need.

Also `makefile-imenu-generic-expression` is constructed from `makefile-macroassign-regex` so you need to reconstruct the value of that variable as well.

I demonstrate that by a self-defined major mode derived from `makefile-mode`.
The most important change in that major mode is the added `+`-sign in the character groups of `makefile-macroassign-regex`.

```el
(define-derived-mode my-makefile-mode makefile-mode "myMake"
  "Makefiles with additional operator +=."
  (setq-local makefile-macroassign-regex
              "\\(?:^\\|^export\\|^override\\|:\\|:[ \t]*override\\)[ \t]*\\([^ \n\t+][^:#= \t\n+]*\\)[ \t]*\\(?:!=\\|[*:+]?[:?]?=\\)")
  (setq-local makefile-font-lock-keywords
              (makefile-make-font-lock-keywords
               makefile-var-use-regex
               makefile-statements
               t))
  (setq-local makefile-imenu-generic-expression
              `(("Dependencies" makefile-previous-dependency 1)
                ("Macro Assignment" ,makefile-macroassign-regex 1))))
```

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for taking the time to explain such a complicated situation so clearly.